# Searching a Numpy array column for 3 or more consecuative values. Then taking a value from another column

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Essentially I want to scan a numpy array column for 3 or consecutive values. If there are 3 or more consecutive values I would like to take another value from the same row different column for where the consecutive values started and then end.

Example

```
numpy arr = [
  [2, 7, 2, 1]
  [1, 2, 3, 4]
  [4, 6, 6, 4]
  [8, 2, 6, 4]
  [9, 3, 1, 4]
  [2, 7, 2, 1]
]
```

From the array above. I want to scan col 4 to see if 4 occurs more then 3 times in a row. If it does I want to take the value from the second col where it starts and ends and store in another array. In this case it would be 3 and 1

Comment: Could you please provide us with your desired output array for the above example? thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this using pandas by shifting the column you want to compare to detect for changes and counting how many times that column repeats.

You did not specify the case of what happens if you have multiple repeats of the same series of numbers, so I will provide a generic solution for that. If you know beforehand that the same sequence of numbers cannot be repeated again, you can probably simplify this solution.

```
# Imports and define data
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

data = [[2, 7, 2, 1],
        [1, 2, 3, 4],
        [4, 6, 6, 4],
        [8, 2, 6, 4],
        [9, 3, 1, 4],
        [2, 7, 2, 1]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'])

# Compare the last column, see where we have a change and label it 1
df['shift'] = df['D'].shift()
df['change'] = np.where(df['D'] == df['shift'], 0, 1)

# Assign a group number for each change (in case same sequence repeats later)
df['group'] = df['change'].cumsum()

# Build a dictionary mapping no. of repeats to group number and assign back to df
consecutives = df.groupby('group')['D'].count()
df['num_consecutives'] = df['group'].map(consecutives)

# Specify the number of consecutives to filter by, group by the "group" col
# and the last col in case there are repeats, so you can identify each instance
# of the first and last appearances, then find the first and last values of 
# the col of interest. You mention 3 and 1, so I assume that's the third col.
df[df['num_consecutives']>3].groupby(['group', 'D'])['C'].agg(['first', 'last'])
```

Comment: This almost works perfectly. This only issue I have is if 1 occurs 3 or more times as well. It records the start and end time for that as well. I only want it to occur for 2's in the list. The list is 14k rows long and there will be several times it reoccurs.

Comment: Since the output of the above is a dataframe with your last column as one of the columns, you can simply filter out the values you don't need.
`output = df[df['num_consecutives']>3].groupby(['group', 'D'])['C'].agg(['first', 'last']).reset_index()`

 
`output[output['D'] != 1]  # Or any other criteria`

Comment: I am not very god at coding sorry does that output[output['D'] != 1] go at the end of the output = df[df['num_consecutives']>3].groupby(['group', 'D'])['C'].agg(['first', 'last']).reset_index() or does it go into a new line.

Comment: New line, I can't insert a code block with comments, so it looks like the same line, but it should be on the next.